# Treating tree disease that manifests as warts/galls/bumps on leaves

Tags: identification, trees, diseases, tree-care

I am trying to identify cause of the problem we have with our tree and the best way to treat it. Here is the image showing the growth on the tree's leaves:

[image: Growth, warts, galls, bumps on leaves]

Is this cause for concern? We really want to preserve the tree as it's old and majestic and could spend money on professionals if this is treatable.

Also, is there anything we can do on our own? Fertilize tree? Spray at root? Basically any suggestion that will help long-term care of tree is welcome.

Answer (score 7):

I can't tell what tree that leaf has come from, so it's difficult to identify precisely the cause of the galls on the leaf. Regardless, the vast majority of gall growths like this do not cause harm to the host tree, and are not a 'disease' - but it can make it look a bit unsightly. Galls are caused by mites or wasps, sometimes bacteria or fungal invasion, and the gall is the response.

There is no treatment, by and large; further information on galls here

(http://idl.entomology.cornell.edu/files/2013/11/Galls-on-Plants-158myw7.pdf)